# Trying to delete buildings selectively from a CityGML

Tags: select, select-by-location, erase, citygml, building

I'm currently working on refining my cityGML file by selectively removing certain buildings. My objective is to include specific neighboring buildings within designated building blocks while deleting the rest. To accomplish this, I've been using the FZK Viewer, which allows me to visually identify the buildings. However, I've encountered a limitation in FZK Viewer—it doesn't seem to allow me to select multiple buildings by simply clicking on them in the viewport. Also, I am not sure if I can delete the buildings permanently from the CityGML file using a viewer.

I'm seeking alternative methods for the building cleaning process without relying on manual selection from a list of building IDs. (since it is quite challenging to know the location of each building by looking at their ID on a list) Ultimately, my goal is to generate a cleaned cityGML file as the output.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I would at least consider importing CityGML into 3dcitydb. However, I do not know how good tools there are for editing. QGIS seems to have a plugin https://www.3dcitydb.org/3dcitydb/